# How To Read The Code Sample At Immutable / React Document Pages

Tags: javascript, facebook, syntax, reactjs, immutable.js

I actually have been confused for a few days & finally decided to ask the question.

The facebook team uses this code style on React & [Immutable pages](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/of). Could someone please explain how to read these.

Here is a copy of the code from the page linked:

```
List.of<T>(...values: T[]): List<T>
```

How are we suppose to read this?

Comment: What are confused about? The type annotations? In this example, `List.of` takes a variable number of arguments of type `T` and returns a list object of type `List<T>`. Have a look at the Flow or Typescript documentation.

Comment: @FelixKling Just general, how to read that code. Whats <T>, T[ ]:List<T>. As I said, the whole line doesnt make sense to me.

Comment: These are all type annotations. Maybe this is a better example: https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Collection/count. Having type annotations in the docs tells you the type of the values the function expects or returns (e.g. number). For your example, you want look into "generics". It's relatively common in typed languages: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Generics.md.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This -

```
List.of<T>(...values: T[]): List<T>
```

Means this -

> The function List.of<any type>(takes one or more items of
>   that type) : and returns a List<of that type>.

Yet another example from their docs -

```
update(index: number, notSetValue: T, updater: (value: T) => T): List<T>
```

Means this -

> The function update(takes index, which is a number, notSetValue which is of any type, and updater which is a function (which takes in value of that type) => and returns that type) and returns a List of that type.

Comment: Thanks HazardouS for the elaboration.

Comment: I find the TypeScript Handbook a great companion guide in "deciphering" the Immutable documentation (as I also had similar problem recently). Turns out it's all standard TypeScript syntax - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

Comment: Great comparison. The same syntax was also popularized by Pascal.